# Report on which Options are selected

Tags: twilio

[twilio] I have a "handle_digits.php" file which provides callers with 4 options. Is it possible to extract a report that shows which options each mobile number actually chose?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is no built in way to do this.  You would need to log the callers selection in your application in order to be able to report on it at a later date.

Hope that helps.